# Laravel MSSQL Server Connection not working

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, database-connection

Laravel version:`7.13`, SqlServer:`2019`

```
 SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: 
 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (SQL: select * from [users]).
```

Above is error message what I got.

I tried with core php and it works well.

Below is php code.

```
<?php

$serverName = "MYPCNAME";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBNAME", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>'MyPassword');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";

     if(($result = sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users")) !== false){
        while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $result )) {
              echo $obj->name.'<br />';
        }
    }

}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

I think SQL Server configuration is correct. I installed php_sqlsrv, php_pdo_sqlsrv extensions and they are displayed as installed in `phpinfo()`

Here is my Laravel configuration.

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=MYPCNAME
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=DBNAME
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=MyPassword
```

Following is database config file.

```
 'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

I tried to change `DB_HOST` with `127.0.0.1` too but there was same issue.
I was going to get users from users table.

---

My thought: I changed server name with `127.0.0.1` in core php and it displayed exact same error with laravel.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing your SQL Server port?

Comment: In TCP/IP configuration?

Comment: Even I changed port and restarted SQLServer, core php worked well. But not laravel.

Comment: In core php too, if I change $serverName = "MYPCNAME, 1434", it displays same issue with laravel. I just changed port to 1434. It seems port issue.

Comment: try running `php artisan tinker` and let me see the output of your env variables

Comment: https://prnt.sc/srolq6 here is tinker output.

Comment: I think the issue is in somewhere sqlserver. https://prnt.sc/sroqrp
If I put port like above image, it should work well, shouldn't it?
I think Laravel also connects like above.$server =  "servername, port".
In php, if I remove port, it works well but if I put it, it didn't work.
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I sovled issue.

When I set `DB_PORT=null` it worked.

However, I didn't find the exact answer yet.

Here is post url about it.

[PHP Sqlsrv connection not working when specify port, instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134472/php-sqlsrv-connection-not-working-when-specify-port-instance)

I think the main reason is above.
Anyway If I set `DB_PORT=null`, it worked successfully.

Comment: You do not need to give DB_PORT parameter itself in env for sqlsrv.

Comment: If we need to change port, then how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just run this command on the terminal. Note that if it was working perfectly before the error

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```