# PHP Sqlsrv connection not working when specify port, instance

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection, php-7, sqlsrv

PHP version:7.4, SQL Server version:2019,

I was going to try to specify port in connection but it didn't work.

```
<?php

$serverName = "MYPCNAME, 1433";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MyDB", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>'MyPassword');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.";

}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

Above showed below message.

```
 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote hos
```

When I removed port like this `$serverName = "MYPCNAME"` , it worked well.

I changed port to 1434, and tested again (Of course I restarted SQL Server, firewall set).

`$serverName = "MYPCNAME, 1434"`

This gave me same error but `$serverName = "MYPCNAME"` This worked well.

I tried to specify instance name too, but there was same issue.

I installed `php_sqlsrv, php_pdo_sqlsrv` well and in `phpinfo()`, they are displayed as installed successfully.

Is there anything what I missed?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: well, I should solve this issue. Because it displays same in Laravel which I am using.
I think Laravel connects with SQL Server as such way. $servername="MYPCNAME, port".

Comment: Did you start the test by making sure which port **Your SQLServer** was in fact listening on

Comment: https://prnt.sc/srqyv0
This is what I can see about port. I think it's running on 1434.